# Print String array of a json payload in splunk

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I need to print a string array along with one field in my json object.

The data:

```
{ "key1":"val1",  "key2":"value2",  "codes":["apple","mango","banana","orange"], "key3_conditional":"yes"}
```

My Search query:

```
<My search query>
| rex "\|(?<payload>[^\|]*)$"
| spath input=payload
| rex "\"codes\":\"(?<codes>[^\"]*)"
| eval is_unknown=if(isnotnull(key3_conditional), key3_conditional, "no")
| table codes, is_unknown
```

Desired result

```
codes                               | is_unknown
--------------------------------------------------
apple, mango, banana, orange        | yes
```

Currently, this only displays the 1st value in codes i.e. `apple` and I need all values of codes as comma separated. I'm supposing there is some issue with my regex. Please suggest.

Comment: You may receive faster responses at https://community.splunk.com/ which is actively monitored by Splunk employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this data is being brought-in a JSON, you won't have to `rex` it out

If not, though, the issue is your regular expression

Try it out on regex101.com - you'll see you're *only* grabbing the first value because you're stopping at a literal `"`

Try this instead:

```
...
| rex field=_raw "codes\":\[(?<codes>[^\]]+)"
| eval codes=split(replace(codes,"\"",""),",")
```

That will make `codes` into a multivalue field

If you don't care about it being multivalue, you can just do:

```
| eval codes=replace(codes,"\"","")
```

to pull the quote marks

Comment: Thanks. That works.  I noticed some issue with that and  I'm using this instead `| rex field=_raw "\"codes\":\[(?<codes>[^\]]+)"`  To capture the field as `"codes"`

Comment: I suppose it was a typo, but the 1st eval had  a `"` missing.  `| eval codes=split(replace(codes,"\"",""),",")`

Comment: @AyushKumar - yep, looks like I missed a quote mark. Fixed now :)